# XSL Transformation, requesting subnode data

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I've just started to play with XSL Transformation - I'd like to use them in order to add additional abstraction layer in my project.

I want to use transformation to convert XML file generated by crystal reports into another XML, simplified for my project (so in future, when schema of file will change, I would only need to change my XSL file).

So my input XML file looks like this:

```
<CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"  
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
    <Group Level="1">
        <GroupHeader>
            <Section SectionNumber="0">
                <Field Name="Field4" FieldName="{@PartIndex}"><FormattedValue>Part Number</FormattedValue><Value>51-01672</Value></Field>
            </Section>
            <Section SectionNumber="1">
                <Text Name="Text28"><TextValue>Part Description</TextValue>
                </Text>
            </Section>
            <Section SectionNumber="2">
                <Text Name="Text21"><TextValue>Part Description 2</TextValue>
                </Text>
            </Section>
            <Section SectionNumber="3">
            </Section>
...
```

That's just a part of it. What I should mention is, that the `GroupHeader` node does not repeat inside of a `Group` node.

So I made some early XSL definitions (for test sake):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:t="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"  
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/t:CrystalReport">
    <ToolsUsage>
        <xsl:value-of select="t:Group[1]/@Level"/>
    </ToolsUsage>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I use lxml Python lib to test it.
This, as expected, returns the following code:

```
<ToolsUsage xmlns:t="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">1</ToolsUsage>
```

So far, so good (Level attribute equals "1" for first Group Node). But I am not able to go any step further.
Like, i tried to get the value of the inner text of the `Field` node (of first section occurrence):

```
<xsl:value-of select="t:Group[1]/GroupHeader/Section[1]/Field/Value"/>
```

But I am not getting anything (in  node as a result). I tried to get a `SectionNumber` attribute, also without a result. I even used an XML path tool to extract the exact XPath query, but it seems, that these queries are correct. I believe it's something very basic, but couldn't find out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `<CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail">...</CrystalReport>`, all descendant elements are as well in the namespace so your paths need to use the prefix on all elements e.g. `t:Group[1]/t:GroupHeader/t:Section[1]/t:Field/t:Value`.